# Geometry Math 8th (Area of a Trapezoid)

Tags: geometry, arithmetic

The windshield in a truck is in the shape of a trapezoid. The lengths of the bases of the trapezoid are 70 inches and 79 inches. The height is 35 inches. Find the area of the glass in the windshield.

Comment: Can you show your effort and point the issue where you have trouble?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The formula for the area of a trapezoid is $\dfrac {a+b}2\times h$, so that becomes $\dfrac {149}2\times35 = 2,607.5$inches$^2$

Answer (score 6):

The average of the two bases is 74.5, and I multiply that by the height which is 35 to get 2607.5 inches.

Comment: not quite, $2607.5$ inch squared

Comment: Oops, I accidentally got the place value wrong, thanks